# How to check connection in Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

My app need to detect if the device is connected to the internet or not. To do this I'm using the below script:

```
   document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.connection.update",function(){
            if(intel.xdk.device.connection == "none")
            {
                   alert("Offline");
            } else {
                  alert("Online");   
           }
        },false);
intel.xdk.device.updateConnection();
```

This code work perfectly in the emulator, but not in my Moto G, using Intel XDK Preview tool or after install the apk generated using Cordova!

Didn't show any fail message, just do nothing!

Comment: have you added Cordova network plugin?

Comment: well... I don't know what are you talk about, so no! How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you added Cordova [Network plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md), you can detect network details as:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

Following links explain how to use Intel-xdk bridge to call different APIs

- Intel XDK Cordova API Documentation
- Intel XDK "legacy" API Documentation
- Apache Cordova* API Documentation

https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/xdkdocs#506911

[Intel XDK Name Space API Plugin Details for Cordova Build Containers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/507858)

Note that the APIs listed below augment the standard Cordova APIs, **both APIs can and should be used in your application**. In some cases there is overlap between the Cordova APIs and the intel.xdk APIs; in that case, we **recommend** you use the **Cordova API first** and then use the intel.xdk API when the Cordova API either does not provide the desired functionality or provides inadequate functionality.

Check this out, it will help you configure the plugin: [Understanding the Intel® XDK Cordova Build Options](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/using-the-cordova-for-android-ios-etc-build-option)

Comment: You can call Cordova/PhoneGap API in the app as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have knowledge about this... I downloaded the network.js and the connection.js from the link that you send me and added this to index.html, but you script didn't works... how to do this?

Comment: yes!!! it works! tks!!! If possible, could you help me with this issue too:https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=8758    maybe I need to config something....

Comment: Ok good, Let me check it out. Its better you open/ask a new question on that issue, in this way other guys will help as well.